# Image does not appear if in _posts/ directory

Tags: jekyll

Image does not appear in local host if saved in the `_posts/` directory but appears if stored in another directory, e.g. `posts/`. Does anyone know why?

`.md` file:

```
![pressure plot]({{ site.baseurl }}/posts/fig/pressure-1.png)  # appears
![pressure plot]({{ site.baseurl }}/_posts/fig/pressure-1.png) # doesnt appear
```

`.html` file from the `.md` file:

```
<img src="/my-awesome-site/posts/fig/pressure-1.png" alt="pressure plot" />
<img src="/my-awesome-site/_posts/fig/pressure-1.png" alt="pressure plot" />
```

`config_yml`:

```
baseurl: /my-awesome-site
```

Error message in Terminal after `jekyll serve` for `_posts/`:

```
ERROR `/my-awesome-site/_posts/fig/pressure-1.png' not found.
```

And the path in the error is actually correct (yes, the images can be found in `_posts/fig/`, I was testing things out by saving in different directories), but somehow the image just doesn't appear. Can anyone explain?

I dont think all these explain: [OSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34444843/blogging-with-jekyll-rmarkdown-and-github-how-to-display-images), [OSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28820917/jekyll-on-github-pages-not-displaying-images-and-has-broken-links), [OSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40695428/baseurl-not-applying-to-jekyll-posts/40697391#40697391), [Jekyll](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/github-pages/#project-page-url-structure), unless I'm not understanding this whole thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking in [Jekyll's documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/structure/), `_posts` is one of the "reserved" directory, parsed by Jekyll for files named with the format `YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP`. Apart from the particular directories:

> Every other directory and file except for those listed above [...] will be copied verbatim to the generated site.

So your image, while existing in your sources, will not be copied in the generated site (see the content of `_site/`), since it is in the directory `_posts` while not being named with the wanted format.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same issue today. Turns out there's a useful plugin for resolving this issue called `jekyll-postfiles`!

[Link to jekyll-postfiles](https://github.com/nhoizey/jekyll-postfiles)

To install `jekyll postiles`, add the following to your `GEMFILE`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'jekyll'

group :jekyll_plugins do
  gem 'jekyll-postfiles'
end
```

Then run `bundle`. That's it!

Suppose you have the following structure:

```
_posts
    |
    |--> folder_a
         |
         |--> year-month-date-filename1.md
         |--> picture.png
    |
    |--> folder_b
         |
         |--> year-month-date-filename2.md
         |--> another_picture.ong
```

Then in `filename1.md`, you can invoke the image as:

```
<img src="picture1.png" width="700" height="500" class="center">
```

This is a very neat way instead of just putting pictures in a separate `assets` folder IMO.

Note: This plugin is not supported by Github Pages, host your site on services like https://netlify.com which support third party plugins.